# How to only allow approved users to log in to my wiki?

Tags: authentication, hook, mediawiki

I have added a column in my wikidatabase in the user table called `approved_account`.
The standard value on that column is `0` (zero).

I would like to add an exception when a user tries to log in to the wiki, such that 
if `approved_account = 0` then the login attempt is denied.

Does anyone know how and where I should place that if statement?

---

**Edit:** I've come this far.
I am using the AbortLogin hook, since I need to verify if my statement is true every time a user tries to log in.

However, my code won't let *anyone* in. It blocks all login attempts, even if I have the correct value in the `approved_account` field.
Can anyone help me fix this?

```
<?php
/** 
* Prevent a user from accessing this file directly and provide a helpful 
* message explaining how to install this extension.
*/
if ( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
    echo <<<EOT
To install the Test extension, put the following line in your LocalSettings.php file: 
require_once( "$IP/extensions/approvedaccount.php" );
EOT;
    exit( 1 );
}

// Extension credits that will show up on Special:Version
$wgExtensionCredits['parserhook'][] = array(
    'name' => 'Approved Account extension',
    'description' => 'Prevent login',
    'author' => 'Me',
    'url' => 'http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:approvedaccount'
);
$wgHooks['AbortLogin'][] = 'approvedaccount::onAbortLogin';

class approvedaccount
{
    public static function onAbortLogin( $user, $password, &$retval ) {
    global $wgOut, $wgUser;

    $dbr = wfGetDB( DB_SLAVE );
    $res = $dbr->select(
    'user',                                     // $table
    array( 'user_name', 'approved_account' ),   // $vars (columns of the table)
    'user_name = "'.$wgUser.'"',                // $conds
    __METHOD__,                                 // $fname = 'Database::select',
    array( 'ORDER BY' => 'user_name ASC' )      // $options = array()
    );

    $output = '';
    foreach( $res as $row ) {
    $output .= 'Användarnamn: ' . $row->user_name . ' , Approved Account: ' . $row->approved_account . ".";
    }

    if ($row->approved_account = "1"){
    //$this->loadDefaults();
    //  return false;
    header("Location: http://hbg-whirlpool.emea.stream.corp/index.php?title=Special:UserLogout&returnto=Main+Page");
    exit();  // you need to exit after a Location header is sent
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: No one that have some sugestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a simple [AuthPlugin](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/AuthPlugin), overriding the `strictUserAuth()` method to return true for users that match the condition.

However, I suspect you're approaching this problem the wrong way.  Why not just define a new [user group](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aUser_rights), say, `approved`, and then add the corresponding record to the [user_groups table](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User_groups_table) for approved users?  You won't be able to prevent unapproved users from logging in, but you *can* prevent them from making edits by only granting the `edit` permission to the approved group, like this:

```php
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['approved']['edit'] = true;
```

(If you wanted, you could even revoke the `read` permission from unapproved users too, but please read the warnings about [restricting read access in MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aPreventing_access#Restrict_viewing_of_all_pages) first.)

---

**Edit:** I see a couple of problems with your AbortLogin hook.

- Doing a 301 redirect and an `exit()` in the middle of the hook is probably not a very good idea.  Sure, it probably *will* abort the login, but that's not really how the hook is meant to be used.  Rather, you should just have the hook function return `false` to indicate that the login should be aborted or `true` to proceed with the normal login checks.
- In any case, you're doing the `exit()` when the `approved_account`  column is `1`, which is presumably exactly when you *don't* want to abort the login.
- ...or, rather, you're doing the `exit()` always, because you used the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==` in the condition, causing it to be always true.  (Don't worry, that's a common bug in PHP and other C-like languages.  One way to avoid is to get in the habit of using "Yoda conditionals" like `1 == $row->approved_account`, which will produce an error if you leave out one `=`, since you can't assign to `1`.)
- Also, concatenating a User object with a string probably won't produce anything meaningful; and, even if it did, there would be an SQL injection vulnerability there.  And besides, the hook parameters already include a User object, so you should use that instead of the global `$wgUser` (which might be stale during login anyway).

I admit that some of this stuff is really poorly documented.  Besides the [AbortLogin](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/AbortLogin) docs, I'd suggest looking at the [general MediaWiki hook documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks), as well as the actual way the hook is called from [SpecialUserlogin.php](https://github.com/brion/MediaWiki/blob/master/includes/specials/SpecialUserlogin.php).  For the database access, I'd also point you to the [database wrapper function docs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aDatabase_access#Wrapper_functions); unfortunately, the [method documentation pages](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classDatabaseBase.html) are giving 404 errors right now, so you'd again need to [look directly in the source](https://github.com/brion/MediaWiki/blob/master/includes/db/Database.php) for the documentation.

Anyway, I'd rewrite your hook like this:

```php
public static function onAbortLogin( $user, $password, &$retval, &$msg ) {
    $dbr = wfGetDB( DB_SLAVE );
    $row = $dbr->selectRow(
        'user',
        'approved_account',
        array( 'user_id' => $user->getID() ),
        __METHOD__
    );

    if ( !$row || !$row->approved_account ) {
        $retval = LoginForm::ABORTED;  // actually the default, but let's be sure
        $msg = 'login-abort-not-approved';  // optional: custom error message
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // account is approved, return true to proceed with other login checks
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you want the custom message, you'll also need to create the page `MediaWiki:login-abort-not-approved` on your wiki.  (If you wanted to turn this into a proper MediaWiki extension, you could [provide a default message in an i18n file](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aSpecial_pages#Basic_special_page_template), but that's probably overkill here.)

---

**Edit 2:** Yes, you can add as many hooks as you want in an extension.  (In fact, you don't even *need* an extension, it's perfectly fine to define simple site-specific hooks directly in LocalSettings.php if you want.)  I *think* something like this could work for an [AddNewAccount hook](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/AddNewAccount) to log the user out, although I must note that I haven't actually tested this:

```php
public static function onAddNewAccount( $user, $byEmail ) {
    global $wgUser;
    // try to log out the new user only if they're actually logged in
    if ( $user->getName() == $wgUser->getName() ) $user->logout();
    return true;
}
```

The `if` clause is there because the AddNewAccount is also called when a user creates a new account while logged in to a pre-existing account, in which case logging them out from their original account would be an unwelcome surprise.  (Technically, just `if ( $user == $wgUser )` ought to suffice, but explicitly comparing the usernames rather than the object references seems safer.)

Note that logging the new user out at that point kind of yanks the carpet out from under the new user creation code, so some unusual things may happen.  For example, I suspect that the user creation log may actually end up saying something like "NewUserName created the new user account NewUserName", and the "Account successfully created" page may temporarily show the user as logged in, even though they're actually not.

It would be much cleaner to somehow avoid the auto-login behavior in the first place, but I don't see any obvious way to do that without patching SpecialUserlogin.php: the only check that determines whether the new user is automatically logged in is `if ( $this->getUser()->isAnon() )`, which only checks whether a user is already logged in.  Even faking that somehow (which would be an ugly kluge in itself) doesn't really seem practical, as far as I can tell.

If you don't mind patching the MediaWiki core, though, just replacing that condition with `if ( false )` (or `if ( false && $this->getUser()->isAnon() )`, if you want to keep it self-documenting) should do the trick.  Note that you could still keep the AddNewAccount hook as a backup, in case you forget to reapply the patch after upgrading or something.

Comment: The edit suggestion have I thought about, but I really would like to be able to control the account creation by approving them access like this.
There is extensions created for things like this but they require email functionallity which I can´t use.
That´s why I would like to allow them to create the account (so that they set their own password) and then they don´t have access untill I let them.

Comment: Disabling edit access basically lets unapproved users log in (and play with their preferences, watchlists, etc.) but not actually change the wiki in any way. If you don't want to allow unapproved account creation at all, the [ConfirmAccount extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ConfirmAccount) might be useful. Or you could at least see how it works and use it as a model for your own extension.

Comment: ConfirmAccount requires mail functionallity so I can´t use it right away.
Unfortunately my scripting skills are very limited why I asked here incase someone had a simple solution for what I was asking about.
As far as I understand what´s needed is that when a user creates an account or login the verification part of the loginprocess also needs to check if approved_account column contains 0 or 1. If 0 they should not be allowed to login.

Comment: Hmm, there seems to be an [AbortLogin hook](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/AbortLogin) that could probably be used for this.  However, I'm not sure if that hook runs also after account creation, so you might need to use another hook ([AddNewAccount](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/AddNewAccount)?) to force a logout immediately after the initial sign-up.

Comment: AbortLogin hook might work.
Below is the code I´ve tried to put together.
But it blocks all login attempts.
How to solve that issue?

Comment: Ilmari Karonen you made my day!!!
I tried your code and it worked perfect!
Thanks!
The rest (how to administrate the access shouldn´t be a problem!
Thanks again!!

Comment: Just one more thing.
Can I add the $wgHooks['AddNewAccount'][] to the same extension aswell so that it force user to logout after account creation?

Comment: Yes, you can have as many hooks per extension as you want; see edit above.

Comment: Thanks alot!
I´ve implemented both hooks you helped me with, choosed to keep them as an extension to simplify it for me.
It works as intended!
The fact they see the welcome page doesn´t bother me, will see if I can change the information on that page so that user will be aware that they can´t use their account untill admin approved them.